# How do i implement Paypal in the Chronoform Redirect

Tags: joomla, paypal

I have a page with joomla and Chronoforms on it.  How do i use the redirect to send it to my paypal page?  An example or a screen shot will help me i don't know why i don't get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need the PayPal redirector from ChronoEngine.com.  ($30) Be advised it only works the PP Advanced API.  Which is where most people choke on the process.